# COGNOS: Calculation in a cross table based on condition from other dimension

Tags: reporting, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

. 
Hello all,

does anyone now if there is a function to calculate a measure based on 'Assets' with the condition of "Profit Center Contribution" or "Funding Center Contribution". (see image below)

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: A few questions.  Is this Cognos 10.2.2?  
Is this a relational model, DMR, or a Cube?
Can you make changes in Framework Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a DMR model you could use the tuple function.  Assets -FCC= tuple(Profit Center Contribution, assets, currentmeasure)

Comment: Even non DMR (cube) sources have a tuple function

Answer (score 1):

I know you already found a solution,

drag your Data item to the end of "Assets" and make it nested.

[image]

Some think like this,

[image]

if you want exact "Assests-FCC"  then create additional QueryCalculation1 = Col1+'-'+Col2.
And add QueryCalculation1 to left of Crosstab.